# Что не так с этим объектом?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

var ping = CallTransport(defaultNetwork,"hello",[]);
console.log(ping);

В консоли: Object { jsonrpc: "2.0", id: 1, result: "HELLO" }

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
const CallTransport = (network,method,dat) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataFetch = async () => {
      const data = await (
        await fetch("http://"+network+"/"+method,{
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                          id: 1,
                          jsonrpc: "2.0",
                          method: method,
                          params: dat,
                          
                        }),
                    })
      ).json();

      setData(data);
    };

    dataFetch();
  }, []);

  return data;
}

export default CallTransport;
```

при console.log(ping.result); console.log(ping["result"]);

билд пишет TS18048: 'ping' is possibly 'undefined'.

собственно, что не так с этим объектом?

Comment: Все правильно пишет. Начальное значение для возвращаемого data undefined. Перед обращением к ключу объекта, его необходимо проверить, что бы не получить ошибку

Comment: const dataFetch = async () => {
    var data = Object.create({id: 0});
      data = await (... Сделал так. Заработало. Спасибо

Comment: Тем не менее чудеса продолжаются var status = JSON.stringify(CallTransport(defaultNetwork,"hello",[])); выдаёт string {"jsonrpc":"2","id":1,"result":{"status":"HELLO"}}. При попытке её парсить JSON.parse(status) даёт ошибку парсинга. JSON.parse('{"jsonrpc":"2","id":1,"result":{"status":"HELLO"}}'); а так - парсит. Что не нравится?...